# ASP.NET and HTML5 Video play time

Tags: asp.net, html, video

Good afternoon stackoverflow!

Currently I'm working on a handler to serve videos from a database to a control that will display it using HTML5. Using Response.OutputStream.Write does indeed work, however, the video player in both Firefox 4.0 and Chrome cannot seem to determine how long the video is. Firefox's counter just increases as the play time goes on, while Chrome shows a completely random time.

Is there some header that I need to set in order for this to work? I have set the content-length to the number of bytes, which I think is the correct value.

**HTML Markup**

```
<video controls="controls" poster="<%= ImageURL %>" width="<%= Width %>" height="<%= Height %>" preload="preload">
    <source src="<%= MP4URL %>" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2"'/>
    <source src="<%= OggURL %>" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora,vorbis"'/>
    <img alt="<%= ImageAlt %>" src="<%= ImageURL %>" width="<%= Width %>" height="<%= Height %>" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
</video>
</div>
```

**Video Handler Code**

```
        // Snip -- Company specific DB code

        // Set the correct headers
        context.Response.AppendHeader("content-length", video.Length.ToString());

        // Set the content type
        switch (extensionType.ToLower())
        {
            case "ogv":
                contentType = "video/ogg";
                break;

            case "mp4":
                contentType = "video/mp4";
                break;

            default:
                contentType = "";
                break;
        }
        context.Response.ContentType = contentType;
        context.Response.Charset = String.Empty;
        context.Response.Buffer = false;


        // Write the video to the stream
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(video, 0, video.Length);

        // Close the repsonse
        context.Response.Close();
        context.Response.End();
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We never found a solution to this issue. In the end that part of the project was canned. A shame because it would have really added something. Hopefully someone will discover the cause/solution. I would personally love to know what on earth was causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a couple of years away from this, we decided to have another look at a video handler. One plucky young apprentice, who has since become a full time developer with us, solved the issue.

As it turns out, you need to add a little more information to the header of your response. We were missing the Content-Range header, which looks like this: bytes_from-bytes_to/bytes_total. The Content-Length header needs to have the size of the chunk that is being sent back instead of the total size of the file. Finally, you need to respond with a code of 206 (partial) instead of 200 (OK).

Once we'd done that, everything started working nicely. We did a bit more to split the files into nice chunks efficiently instead of loading the whole file from the database again and again.